Access to a server by ssh
Good afternoon.
I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 23.10 which I can access to the console without problems (as root user). The problem is when I want to access it via winscp from Windows (sftp) or via ssh from another Linux, it denies me the access, saying that the password entered is incorrect (as root user). SSH is configured to allow root connections. I tried to change the root password, but I still can't access. I would like to know if the local root password should be the same as the ssh root user or if the ssh root user is different from the local one and it is that one that I should change the password for.
Thank you very much.

Make sure you're entering the correct password by running su and entering root's password, that /etc/ssh/sshd_config contains PermitRootLogin yes, that you have restarted the SSH service by running sudo systemctl restart ssh.service. If that doesn't avail, look for additional configuration files in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d, making sure no one contains directives such as AllowUsers / DenyUsers. If those files are clean, maybe try and set UsePAM to no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (although defaults should be sane), just in case something's up with PAM.

By the way no, the password used to login via SSH is the same you use to log in locally. Regardless, I wouldn't even bother setting up password-based authentication if you are not concerned with users in physical presence possibly SSHing into your VM as root, I'd just use SSH keys.

One common reason for "access denied" is erroneously trying to connect to the wrong machine, particularly if the VM is behind NAT or otherwise on a different subnet.
